# Move data from root ZFS into child filesystem

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas, zpool

I have a zpool (pool verion 13, FS version 3, called tank0) with about 2.5TB of data in the root of the pool (i.e. directly in /mnt/tank0). OS is FreeBSD, actually FreeNAS version 0.7.2.

I would like to move all of that data to a child filesystem (i.e. one created with zfs create tank0/work) in line with best practice (that I know now).

Not too bothered about keeping the snapshots, but I am bothered about ensuring continual data integrity. I am also space constrained - not enough disk space to just backup and restore to the new location.

Is this possible? Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the snapshots, I'd probably just run `mv` in a `screen` session. Do you have any logical groupings of data that you can move piecemeal? I'm not sure what other options you have if you can't offload the data to another set of storage.

Comment: Several days later, done. Thanks for the simple suggestion.